# Biblatex: Shorthands or aliases with authoryear-comp

Tags: biblatex

How can I use shorthands or aliases with the citation style `authoryear-comp`? Specifically, I would like to have

First text citation:

> Bravo & Charlie (2002, hereafter Paper I)
>
> Bravo & Charlie (2002, hereafter Paper I) and Charlie & Delta (2004)
>
> Bravo & Charlie (2002, hereafter Paper I, 2003) and Charlie & Delta (2004)
>
> Bravo & Charlie (2001, 2002, hereafter Paper I) and Charlie & Delta (2004)
>
> Alpha & Bravo (2000) and Bravo & Charlie (2002, hereafter Paper I)

First parenthesized citation:

> (Bravo & Charlie 2002, hereafter Paper I)
>
> (Bravo & Charlie 2002, hereafter Paper I; Charlie & Delta 2004)
>
> (Bravo & Charlie 2002, hereafter Paper I, 2003; Charlie & Delta 2004)
>
> (Bravo & Charlie 2001, 2002, hereafter Paper I; Charlie & Delta 2004)
>
> (Alpha & Bravo 2000; Bravo & Charlie 2002, hereafter Paper I)

Subsequent text citations:

> Paper I
>
> Paper I and Charlie & Delta (2004)
>
> Paper I, Bravo & Charlie (2003), and Charlie & Delta (2004)
>
> Bravo & Charlie (2001), Paper I, and Charlie & Delta (2004)
>
> Alpha & Bravo (2000) and Paper I

Subsequent parenthesized citations:

> (Paper I)
>
> (Paper I; Charlie & Delta 2004)
>
> (Paper I; Bravo & Charlie 2003; Charlie & Delta 2004)
>
> (Bravo & Charlie 2001; Paper I; Charlie & Delta 2004)
>
> (Alpha & Bravo 2000; Paper I)

The style is based off the Astrophysical Journal (ApJ). I am not aware of specific instructions regarding punctuations and sorting in the case of shorthands or aliases, so the examples above may be slightly incorrect.

It is easy enough to get the ApJ style from `authoryear-comp` with

```
\renewcommand*\finalnamedelim
  {\ifbibliography{\finalandcomma}{}\addspace\&\space}
\renewcommand*\nameyeardelim{\addspace}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{citedas={hereafter}}
```

but hacking `authoryear-comp` to get shorthands or aliases to work is beyond me.

**Edit 1:** Per comment from @moewe, here is a test example. Shorthands are of course not yet working as intended. (Curious note: `0` cannot be used as an entry key.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{1,
  author    = "Alpha, A. and Bravo, B.",
  year      = "2000"
}
@article{2,
  author    = "Bravo, B. and Charlie, C.",
  year      = "2001"
}
@article{3,
  author    = "Bravo, B. and Charlie, C.",
  year      = "2002",
  shorthand = "Paper I"
}
@article{4,
  author    = "Bravo, B. and Charlie, C.",
  year      = "2003"
}
@article{5,
  author    = "Charlie, C. and Delta, D.",
  year      = "2004"
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname}
\renewcommand*\finalnamedelim
  {\ifbibliography{\finalandcomma}{}\addspace\&\space}
\renewcommand*\nameyeardelim{\addspace}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{citedas={hereafter}}
\begin{document}
\parindent0em\relax
\textcite{3}\citereset\par
\textcite{3, 5}\citereset\par
\textcite{3, 4, 5}\citereset\par
\textcite{2, 3, 5}\citereset\par
\textcite{1, 3}\citereset\vskip\bigskipamount
\parencite{3}\citereset\par
\parencite{3, 5}\citereset\par
\parencite{3, 4, 5}\citereset\par
\parencite{2, 3, 5}\citereset\par
\parencite{1, 3}\vskip\bigskipamount
\textcite{3}\par
\textcite{3, 5}\par
\textcite{3, 4, 5}\par
\textcite{2, 3, 5}\par
\textcite{1, 3}\vskip\bigskipamount
\parencite{3}\par
\parencite{3, 5}\par
\parencite{3, 4, 5}\par
\parencite{2, 3, 5}\par
\parencite{1, 3}
\end{document}
```

**Edit 2:** Here is an extended test followed by expected results.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, citetracker, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{1,
  author    = "Alpha, A. and Bravo, B.",
  year      = "2001"
}
@article{2,
  author    = "Bravo, B. and Charlie, C.",
  year      = "2002"
}
@article{3,
  author    = "Bravo, B. and Charlie, C.",
  year      = "2003"
}
@article{4,
  author    = "Bravo, B. and Charlie, C.",
  year      = "2004",
  shorthand = "Paper I"
}
@article{5,
  author    = "Bravo, B. and Charlie, C.",
  year      = "2005"
}
@article{6,
  author    = "Bravo, B. and Charlie, C.",
  year      = "2006"
}
@article{7,
  author    = "Charlie, C. and Delta, D.",
  year      = "2007"
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname}
\renewcommand*\finalnamedelim
  {\ifbibliography{\finalandcomma}{}\addspace\&\space}
\renewcommand*\nameyeardelim{\addspace}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{citedas={hereafter}}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}\parindent0em\relax
\textcite{4}\citereset\par
\textcite{1, 4}\citereset\par
\textcite{4, 7}\citereset\par
\textcite{1, 2, 4}\citereset\par
\textcite{1, 4, 5}\citereset\par
\textcite{2, 4, 7}\citereset\par
\textcite{4, 5, 7}\citereset\par
\textcite{1, 2, 3, 4}\citereset\par
\textcite{1, 3, 4, 5}\citereset\par
\textcite{1, 4, 5, 6}\citereset\par
\textcite{2, 3, 4, 7}\citereset\par
\textcite{3, 4, 5, 7}\citereset\par
\textcite{4, 5, 6, 7}\citereset\par
\textcite{1, 2, 3, 4, 7}\citereset\par
\textcite{1, 3, 4, 5, 7}\citereset\par
\textcite{1, 4, 5, 6, 7}\citereset\newpage
\parencite{4}\citereset\par
\parencite{1, 4}\citereset\par
\parencite{4, 7}\citereset\par
\parencite{1, 2, 4}\citereset\par
\parencite{1, 4, 5}\citereset\par
\parencite{2, 4, 7}\citereset\par
\parencite{4, 5, 7}\citereset\par
\parencite{1, 2, 3, 4}\citereset\par
\parencite{1, 3, 4, 5}\citereset\par
\parencite{1, 4, 5, 6}\citereset\par
\parencite{2, 3, 4, 7}\citereset\par
\parencite{3, 4, 5, 7}\citereset\par
\parencite{4, 5, 6, 7}\citereset\par
\parencite{1, 2, 3, 4, 7}\citereset\par
\parencite{1, 3, 4, 5, 7}\citereset\par
\parencite{1, 4, 5, 6, 7}\newpage
\textcite{4}\par
\textcite{1, 4}\par
\textcite{4, 7}\par
\textcite{1, 2, 4}\par
\textcite{1, 4, 5}\par
\textcite{2, 4, 7}\par
\textcite{4, 5, 7}\par
\textcite{1, 2, 3, 4}\par
\textcite{1, 3, 4, 5}\par
\textcite{1, 4, 5, 6}\par
\textcite{2, 3, 4, 7}\par
\textcite{3, 4, 5, 7}\par
\textcite{4, 5, 6, 7}\par
\textcite{1, 2, 3, 4, 7}\par
\textcite{1, 3, 4, 5, 7}\par
\textcite{1, 4, 5, 6, 7}\newpage
\parencite{4}\par
\parencite{1, 4}\par
\parencite{4, 7}\par
\parencite{1, 2, 4}\par
\parencite{1, 4, 5}\par
\parencite{2, 4, 7}\par
\parencite{4, 5, 7}\par
\parencite{1, 2, 3, 4}\par
\parencite{1, 3, 4, 5}\par
\parencite{1, 4, 5, 6}\par
\parencite{2, 3, 4, 7}\par
\parencite{3, 4, 5, 7}\par
\parencite{4, 5, 6, 7}\par
\parencite{1, 2, 3, 4, 7}\par
\parencite{1, 3, 4, 5, 7}\par
\parencite{1, 4, 5, 6, 7}
\end{document}
```

```
Bravo & Charlie (2004, hereafter Paper I)
Alpha & Bravo (2001) and Bravo & Charlie (2004, hereafter Paper I)
Bravo & Charlie (2004, hereafter Paper I) and Charlie & Delta (2007)
Alpha & Bravo (2001) and Bravo & Charlie (2002, 2004, hereafter Paper I)
Alpha & Bravo (2001) and Bravo & Charlie (2004, hereafter Paper I, 2005)
Bravo & Charlie (2002, 2004, hereafter Paper I) and Charlie & Delta (2007)
Bravo & Charlie (2004, hereafter Paper I, 2005) and Charlie & Delta (2007)
Alpha & Bravo (2001) and Bravo & Charlie (2002, 2003, 2004, hereafter Paper I)
Alpha & Bravo (2001) and Bravo & Charlie (2003, 2004, hereafter Paper I, 2005)
Alpha & Bravo (2001) and Bravo & Charlie (2004, hereafter Paper I, 2005, 2006)
Bravo & Charlie (2002, 2003, 2004, hereafter Paper I) and Charlie & Delta (2007)
Bravo & Charlie (2003, 2004, hereafter Paper I, 2005) and Charlie & Delta (2007)
Bravo & Charlie (2004, hereafter Paper I, 2005, 2006) and Charlie & Delta (2007)
Alpha & Bravo (2001), Bravo & Charlie (2002, 2003, 2004, hereafter Paper I), and Charlie & Delta (2007)
Alpha & Bravo (2001), Bravo & Charlie (2003, 2004, hereafter Paper I, 2005), and Charlie & Delta (2007)
Alpha & Bravo (2001), Bravo & Charlie (2004, hereafter Paper I, 2005, 2006), and Charlie & Delta (2007)

(Bravo & Charlie 2004, hereafter Paper I)
(Alpha & Bravo 2001; Bravo & Charlie 2004, hereafter Paper I)
(Bravo & Charlie 2004, hereafter Paper I; Charlie & Delta 2007)
(Alpha & Bravo 2001; Bravo & Charlie 2002, 2004, hereafter Paper I)
(Alpha & Bravo 2001; Bravo & Charlie 2004, hereafter Paper I, 2005)
(Bravo & Charlie 2002, 2004, hereafter Paper I; Charlie & Delta 2007)
(Bravo & Charlie 2004, hereafter Paper I, 2005; Charlie & Delta 2007)
(Alpha & Bravo 2001; Bravo & Charlie 2002, 2003, 2004, hereafter Paper I)
(Alpha & Bravo 2001; Bravo & Charlie 2003, 2004, hereafter Paper I, 2005)
(Alpha & Bravo 2001; Bravo & Charlie 2004, hereafter Paper I, 2005, 2006)
(Bravo & Charlie 2002, 2003, 2004, hereafter Paper I; Charlie & Delta 2007)
(Bravo & Charlie 2003, 2004, hereafter Paper I, 2005; Charlie & Delta 2007)
(Bravo & Charlie 2004, hereafter Paper I, 2005, 2006; Charlie & Delta 2007)
(Alpha & Bravo 2001; Bravo & Charlie 2002, 2003, 2004, hereafter Paper I; Charlie & Delta 2007)
(Alpha & Bravo 2001; Bravo & Charlie 2003, 2004, hereafter Paper I, 2005; Charlie & Delta 2007)
(Alpha & Bravo 2001; Bravo & Charlie 2004, hereafter Paper I, 2005, 2006; Charlie & Delta 2007)

Paper I
Alpha & Bravo (2001) and Paper I
Paper I and Charlie & Delta (2007)
Alpha & Bravo (2001), Bravo & Charlie (2002), and Paper I
Alpha & Bravo (2001), Paper I, and Bravo & Charlie (2005)
Bravo & Charlie (2002), Paper I, and Charlie & Delta (2007)
Paper I, Bravo & Charlie (2005), and Charlie & Delta (2007)
Alpha & Bravo (2001), Bravo & Charlie (2002, 2003), and Paper I
Alpha & Bravo (2001), Bravo & Charlie (2003), Paper I, and Bravo & Charlie (2005)
Alpha & Bravo (2001), Paper I, and Bravo & Charlie (2005, 2006)
Bravo & Charlie (2002, 2003), Paper I, and Charlie & Delta (2007)
Bravo & Charlie (2003), Paper I, Bravo & Charlie (2005), and Charlie & Delta (2007)
Paper I, Bravo & Charlie (2005, 2006), and Charlie & Delta (2007)
Alpha & Bravo (2001), Bravo & Charlie (2002, 2003), Paper I, and Charlie & Delta (2007)
Alpha & Bravo (2001), Bravo & Charlie (2003), Paper I, Bravo & Charlie (2005), and Charlie & Delta (2007)
Alpha & Bravo (2001), Paper I, Bravo & Charlie (2005, 2006), and Charlie & Delta (2007)

(Paper I)
(Alpha & Bravo 2001; Paper I)
(Paper I; Charlie & Delta 2007)
(Alpha & Bravo 2001; Bravo & Charlie 2002; Paper I)
(Alpha & Bravo 2001; Paper I; Bravo & Charlie 2005)
(Bravo & Charlie 2002; Paper I; Charlie & Delta 2007)
(Paper I; Bravo & Charlie 2005; Charlie & Delta 2007)
(Alpha & Bravo 2001; Bravo & Charlie 2002, 2003; Paper I)
(Alpha & Bravo 2001; Bravo & Charlie 2003; Paper I; Bravo & Charlie 2005)
(Alpha & Bravo 2001; Paper I; Bravo & Charlie 2005, 2006)
(Bravo & Charlie 2002, 2003; Paper I; Charlie & Delta 2007)
(Bravo & Charlie 2003; Paper I; Bravo & Charlie 2005; Charlie & Delta 2007)
(Paper I; Bravo & Charlie 2005, 2006; Charlie & Delta 2007)
(Alpha & Bravo 2001; Bravo & Charlie 2002, 2003; Paper I; Charlie & Delta 2007)
(Alpha & Bravo 2001; Bravo & Charlie 2003; Paper I; Bravo & Charlie 2005; Charlie & Delta 2007)
(Alpha & Bravo 2001; Paper I; Bravo & Charlie 2005, 2006; Charlie & Delta 2007)
```

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a short MWE of what you have so far along with a few example entries? That way you can ensure that we actually have something to play around with that comes close to what you use at your end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `-comp` styles are often a bit ugly to modify (one ends up with many lines of codes even for relatively trifling changes).

The modification needed for the `cite` bibmacro, however, is straightforward. Replace the test `\iffieldundef{shorthand}` by `\ifboolexpr{test {\iffieldundef{shorthand}} or not test {\ifciteseen}}` and add `\usebibmacro{shorthandintro}` to the end of the non-shorthand blocks.

Since you want slightly different `\textcite` citations we had to restructure that macro a bit. The `shorthand` logic was moved up a few nesting levels.

In order to get `textcitecount` and friends right, we also had to modify the `\textcite` cite command a bit.

We then also modify the `shorthandintro` macro to fit your wishes.

The relevant code in the MWE below is the bit between `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother`. Note that you need to enable the `citetracker` feature for this to work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, backend=biber, citetracker]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{1,
  author    = "Alpha, A. and Bravo, B.",
  year      = "2000"
}
@article{2,
  author    = "Bravo, B. and Charlie, C.",
  year      = "2001"
}
@article{3,
  author    = "Bravo, B. and Charlie, C.",
  year      = "2002",
  shorthand = "Paper I"
}
@article{4,
  author    = "Bravo, B. and Charlie, C.",
  year      = "2003"
}
@article{5,
  author    = "Charlie, C. and Delta, D.",
  year      = "2004"
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\renewcommand*\finalnamedelim
  {\ifbibliography{\finalandcomma}{}\addspace\&\space}
\renewcommand*\nameyeardelim{\addspace}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{citedas={hereafter}}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\iffieldundef{shorthand}} or not test {\ifciteseen}}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}
       {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
          {\ifthenelse{\iffieldequals{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}\AND
                       \(\value{multicitecount}=0\OR\iffieldundef{postnote}\)}
             {\setunit{\addcomma}%
              \usebibmacro{cite:extrayear}}
             {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
              \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}%
              \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}}
          {\printnames{labelname}%
           \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}%
           \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
           \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}}%
    \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}%
  \setunit{\multicitedelim}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\iffieldundef{shorthand}} or not test {\ifciteseen}}
    {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
       {\ifthenelse{\iffieldequals{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}\AND
                      \(\value{multicitecount}=0\OR\iffieldundef{postnote}\)}
            {\setunit{\addcomma}%
             \usebibmacro{cite:extrayear}}
            {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
             \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}%
             \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}}
        {\ifnameundef{labelname}
           {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
            \setunit{%
              \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
              \printdelim{nonameyeardelim}\bibopenparen}%
            \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
              {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
              {}%
            \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}
           {\printnames{labelname}%
            \setunit{%
              \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
              \printdelim{nameyeardelim}\bibopenparen}%
            \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
              {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
              {}%
            \iffieldundef{labelyear}
               {\usebibmacro{cite:label}}
               {\usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}%
             \savefield{labelyear}{\cbx@lastyear}}%
         \stepcounter{textcitecount}}%
     \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}%
     \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
     \stepcounter{textcitecount}%
     \global\undef\cbx@lasthash
     \global\undef\cbx@lastyear}%
    \setunit{%
      \ifbool{cbx:parens}
        {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
        {}%
      \textcitedelim}}

\renewbibmacro*{shorthandintro}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthandintro}
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {}
       {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \printtext{%
          \bibstring{citedas}\space
          \printfield{shorthand}}}}
    {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \printtext{\printfield{shorthandintro}}}}

%\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}{N}{}\ifciteseen{S}{}\iffieldundef{shorthand}{U}{}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}[\cbx@textcite@init\cbx@textcite]
  {\gdef\cbx@savedkeys{}%
   \citetrackerfalse%
   \pagetrackerfalse%
   \DeferNextCitekeyHook%
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}}
  {\ifthenelse{\iffirstcitekey\AND\value{multicitetotal}>0}
     {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{()(\thefield{multipostnote})}%
      \global\clearfield{multipostnote}}
     {}%
   \xappto\cbx@savedkeys{\thefield{entrykey},}%
   \citetrackertrue
   \ifboolexpr{not test {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}} or (not test {\iffieldundef{shorthand}} and test {\ifciteseen}) }
     {\stepcounter{textcitetotal}%
      \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}%
      \ifboolexpr{not test {\iffieldundef{shorthand}} and test {\ifciteseen}}
        {\global\undef\cbx@lasthash}{}}
     {}%
   \citetrackerfalse}
  {}
  {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{%
     [\thefield{prenote}][\thefield{postnote}]{\cbx@savedkeys}}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\parindent0em\relax
\textcite{3}\citereset\par
\textcite{3, 5}\citereset\par
\textcite{3, 4, 5}\citereset\par
\textcite{2, 3, 5}\citereset\par
\textcite{1, 3}\citereset\vskip\bigskipamount
\parencite{3}\citereset\par
\parencite{3, 5}\citereset\par
\parencite{3, 4, 5}\citereset\par
\parencite{2, 3, 5}\citereset\par
\parencite{1, 3}\vskip\bigskipamount
\textcite{3}\par
\textcite{3, 5}\par
\textcite{3, 4, 5}\par
\textcite{2, 3, 5}\par
\textcite{1, 3}\vskip\bigskipamount
\parencite{3}\par
\parencite{3, 5}\par
\parencite{3, 4, 5}\par
\parencite{2, 3, 5}\par
\parencite{1, 3}
\end{document}
```

[image: four example blocks from OP]

Comment: Thanks! I've tested your fix: it works for all parenthesized citations, but not for subsequent text citations. Using the example you've supplied, I would expect "KpV" on the second line instead of "Kant (KpV)".

Comment: @photon.engine I have modified the `textcite` macro to hopefully give the expected output now. Have a look at the edited answer and let me know.

Comment: This however seems to mess up the "and" connective between multiple groups of authors; for example, in line 2, one would expect "KpV and Sigfridsson & Ryde (1998)". Let me see if I can't understand the code and make a change.

Comment: @photon.engine Ah yes, that required some more work in the innards of the texcite system. Try the edited version and let me know if it works for you, please.

Comment: Thank you for the heroic effort! There are a few edge cases missed out (see my edit above), but they are sufficiently artificial that one may never reasonably encounter them, so I'll mark your answer as accepted. Of course you're more than welcome to take a shot at those weird cases :)

Comment: @photon.engine I believe I could deal with the last problem. Please check the edited answer (I only added a `\global\undef\cbx@lasthash` to the `\global\undef\cbx@lastyear` in the shorthand case for textcite.)

Comment: I think you really did it! Editing my edit above.